# Slick arrows not appearing

Tags: jquery

I was trying to use Slick slider on one of my websites but I cant seem to make the arrows as in the demo, instead they appear like buttons and that looks bad. I download the slick.zip and extracted to my website root directory. I then made the below code changes to my website. The page I am on is products/spice.html so I would have used the reference to slick folder using

> ../slick/*

Code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../slick/slick/slick.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../slick/slick/slick-theme.css"/>
{....}
<button class="btn-prev">Prev</button>
<button class="btn-next">Next</button>
<div class="your-class">
    <div><img src="../img/products/spices/Cardamom.jpeg" /></div>
    <div><img src="../img/products/spices/Cashew.jpeg" /></div>
    <div><img src="../img/products/spices/Cinnamon.jpeg" /></div>
    <div><img src="../img/products/spices/Cloves.jpeg" /></div>
    <div><img src="../img/products/spices/Pepper.jpeg" /></div>
</div>
{....}
<script type="text/javascript" src="../slick/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.your-class').slick({
      infinite: true,
      slidesToShow: 2,
      slidesToScroll: 2,
        dots: true,
        prevArrow: '.btn-prev',
        nextArrow: '.btn-next'
  });
});
</script>
```

But looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have specified your own arrow elements, and those are just normal buttons. If you want the default slick arrows, remove the button elements from your HTML, and just invoke `$.slick()` without specifying `prevArrow` and `nextArrow`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../slick/slick/slick.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../slick/slick/slick-theme.css"/>
{....}
<div class="your-class">
    <div><img src="../img/products/spices/Cardamom.jpeg" /></div>
    <div><img src="../img/products/spices/Cashew.jpeg" /></div>
    <div><img src="../img/products/spices/Cinnamon.jpeg" /></div>
    <div><img src="../img/products/spices/Cloves.jpeg" /></div>
    <div><img src="../img/products/spices/Pepper.jpeg" /></div>
</div>
{....}
<script type="text/javascript" src="../slick/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.your-class').slick({
      infinite: true,
      slidesToShow: 2,
      slidesToScroll: 2,
      dots: true
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: If I do that, no buttons/arrows appear. Its a plain slider with the dots.

Comment: Actually, it worked with your changes, I had to change the color of those arrows to see it :P

Comment: You must add this CSS rule also! `.slick-arrow:before { color: red; }`

Comment: @Alex78191 the buttons are white by default, so they show up against a dark background. https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/dydxjrO. If you need to change that for whatever reason `.slick-arrow:before { color: [color]; }` seems like a good way to do it.